# How to use variable created in SELECT in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling a little bit in figuring out how to use the variable that I created inside the SELECT query in my WHERE clause, whenever I try to use it just to filter some data, the where clause just doesn't know what my variable is.
Here's the query :

```
SELECT a.credit,
       a.disDate,a.id, -t.price, at.tagID,
       @first_month_days := DAY(LAST_DAY(a.disDate)) as firstMonthDays,
       @first_month_day := DAY(a.disDate) as firstMonthDay,
       @first := t.price/@first_month_days*(@first_month_days-@first_month_day) as firstMonthDayBill,
       @second_month_days := DAY(last_day(date_add(a.disDate, interval @first_month_days-@first_month_day + 1 day))) as nextMonthDays,
       @second := t.price/@second_month_days*(IF(40-(@first_month_days - @first_month_day) > @second_month_days,@second_month_days,40 - (@first_month_days - @first_month_day))) as secondMonthDayBill,
       @third_month_days := DAY(last_day(date_add(a.disDate, interval @first_month_days-@first_month_day + @second_month_days + 1 day ))) as thirdMonthDays,
       @third := IF(40 - (@first_month_days - @first_month_day) > @second_month_days,t.price/@third_month_days*(40 - ((@first_month_days-@first_month_day)+@second_month_days)),0) as thirdMonthDayBill,
       a.balance,
       @sum := @second+@first+@third
        FROM ns_accounts a
        INNER JOIN ns_tariffs t ON
        a.tariffID = t.id
        INNER JOIN ns_accounts_tags at ON
        a.id = at.aID
        AND at.tagID IN (13)
        where a.credit is not null and a.disDate is not null and  statusID = 1 and @sum > 0
```

I could make it simpler:

```
SELECT 
       @first := DAY(LAST_DAY(a.number)),
       @second := DAY(LAST_DAY(a.differentNumber))
      
       @sum := @second+@first
        FROM accounts a
        
        where @sum > 0
```

Whats the best way to simply create a variable inside the select query and also be able to use it in the where clause? thank you in advance

Comment: I think you would be safer with a subselect.  From the manual 'The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment' and 'Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL'

Comment: I suggest instead you use something like `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... AS first, ... AS second) t WHERE t.first + t.second > 0`

Comment: Your query won't work correctly! Investigate: https://dbfiddle.uk/7tQeUVop See the above advice..

Comment: You might restate this question explaining what you are trying to achieve publishing sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: why cant you use a CTE to do the job something like below ?

WITH cte_name (column_list) AS (  query with all you calcs ) 
SELECT * FROM cte_name where <variables based on CTE calc>

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan - One can use a CTE, but it gives no advantage over the subquery solution suggested in the comment above by Rob Eyre.

Comment: @BillKarwin, yes you are correct in terms of performance but the query will be more readable even if it is big or complex, also you can use the cte many times within the query.

Comment: I don't see any difference in readability between a CTE solution and a subquery solution. Readability is always going to be a subjective measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can't make any expression in the select-list of a query and reference it in the WHERE clause of the same query. In spite of the fact that select-list expressions occur first in the query syntax, they aren't evaluated until after the WHERE clause has applied row restriction.

This applies to both user defined variables and also aliases.

The workaround is that you can evaluate the expressions in a subquery, then reference them in the outer query.

```
SELECT t2.`first`, t2.`second`, t2.`sum`
FROM (
    SELECT t1.`first`, t1.`second`, t1.`second`+t1.`first` as `sum` 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
           DAY(LAST_DAY(a.number)) as `first`,
           DAY(LAST_DAY(a.differentNumber)) as `second`
        FROM accounts a
    ) AS t1
) AS t2
WHERE t2.`sum` > 0;
```

In this example, there must be two levels of subquery. The `sum` expression can't reference `first` and `second` in the same select-list where those expressions are evaluated. Likewise, the WHERE clause can't reference `sum` in the same query where that expression is evaluated.

With this solution, there is no need for user-defined variables. It's discouraged to make user-defined variables in SQL queries as you were doing anyway, because expressions in the select-list are not guaranteed to be evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you!